# Compare three table values and retrieve a value from both the table using codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have three table

```
student_details

   1.ID
   2.studentname
   3.deptname
   4.deptcode

  login_details

   1.id
   2.username
   3.password
   4.deptcode

 dept_details
   1.id
   2.deptcode
   3.deptname
```

From these table i need to check the username and password from the login_details table and additionally retrieve a deptname from dept_details table by checking the values as student_details.deptcode==login_details.deptcode and dept_details.deptcode==student_details.deptcode.. these the concept then how can i implement  this steps in codeigniter please help someone..
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should have a relation with you're `login_details` and `student_details` the only thing connecting this 3 tables is the `dept_code` i don't think this is a good structure. it is hard to get the login details from the login_details and connect it to the student_details unless you already know the ID of all the data you need

Comment: I write the queries in my localhost phpmyadmin likes "SELECT a.id, a.username, a.deptcode, c.deptname
FROM logindetails a, student_details b, deptdetails c
WHERE a.deptcode = c.deptcode
AND a.deptcode = b.deptcode" Here it works fine. But In codeigniter it not works .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codeigniter you can use the `Active Records` to do this and also by passing your custom query like

```
$username="test";
$password="password";
$query="SELECT dd.deptname,sd.studentname FROM dept_details dd
INNER JOIN login_details ld ON  (dd.deptcode = ld.deptcode)
INNER JOIN student_details sd ON  (ld.deptcode = sd.deptcode)
WHERE ld.username='".$username."' AND ld.password='".$password."' ";
$result=$this->db->query($query)->result();
```

OR

```
$this->db->select('dd.deptname,sd.studentname');
$this->db->from('dept_details dd');
$this->db->join('login_details ld', 'dd.deptcode = ld.deptcode');
$this->db->join('student_details sd', 'd.deptcode = sd.deptcode');
$this->db->where('ld.username', $username);
$this->db->where('ld.password', $password);
$result = $this->db->get();
```

And make sure you have loaded the `database` library in `autoload.php` like 
`$autoload['libraries'] = array("database");`

Here is the help for [Active record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)
Hope it makes sense

Answer (score -2):

Tables **student_details** and **login_details** should be one table. Can a user have multiple login details? And @tomexsans is right, as "student_id" is your unique ID, you should have that ID connecting your tables.

I was thinking about this structure:

Table **student**:

```
student_id
student_name
username
password
dept_id
```

Table **dept_details**:

```
dept_id
dept_code
dept_name
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply . From these two table how can i write the queries to retrieve deptname ..